# How to make the keyboard focus ring to appear on every element in Xamarin.forms?

Tags: ios, swift, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, keyboard-focus

I have a task to make the app in my company to be keyboard accessible and while I manage to make the elements in xamarin.forms focus accessible via keyboard they are not always getting the focusRing highlight as it is supposed to. Is there some option in xamarin forms ios that can make buttons, for example always to get this focusRing highlight.

[Here is a screenshot of the focusRingHighlight](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zZ7xt.png)

Comment: If you turn on VoiceOver and go through the items, the behavior you see is the native behavior, so you shouldn't need to add any additional "focus ring highlight" to all the items, the OS decides that automatically. You can test apple's native apps to verify as well.

Answer (score 0):

There is an IsFocused property in Xamarin, which can determine whether an element is focused. You can use this property to determine that when the button is focused, change the background color to achieve an effect similar to focusRing.

Like this:

```
if (myElement.IsFocused)
  myElement.BackgroundColor = Color.Red;
```

For more details, you can refer to the documentation :

[VisualElement.IsFocused Property | Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.visualelement.isfocused?view=xamarin-forms#Xamarin_Forms_VisualElement_IsFocused)